# How to stop UITableView from reusing image cell data?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My Tableview is reusing previous cell image data and displaying images from previous cells. I did the following to prevent it from reusing. What am I missing?

```
@IBAction func cityBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    for i in stride(from: 0, to: assignCities.count, by: 1)
       { cityName.append(bigCities[i])
         cityImages.append(bigCityImages[i])
        }}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell= tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CityCell
    myCell.myLabel.text = cityName[indexPath.row]

   let cityImg = cityImages[indexPath.row]
    myCell.myImage.image = nil

    if (cityImg != "") 
    {
        myCell.myImage.image = UIImage(named:cityImg)
    }
    else 
    {
        myCell.myImage.image = nil
    }
    return myCell
}


import UIKit
class CityCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var myImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    myImage.image = nil
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
}
```

I did the above but still it is not getting the result

Comment: it is OK behavior, you are reusing cell, so it keeps it state, you need to reset it

Comment: May I know , how to reset it as all my tries are going in vain.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Can you print content of your array? Show your numberOfRows Method and how you'r making your array.

Answer (score 9):

You can implement `func prepareForReuse()` method of `UITableViewCell` and reset your cell properties there.

> This method is invoked just before the object is returned from the UITableView method dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)

```
 func prepareForReuse() {
     super. prepareForReuse()
     myImage.image = nil
 }
```

This had to be implemented inside your custom table view cell class.

Comment: Do you mind guiding me to an example of it's usage as I am finding only one line answers about that function.

Comment: put the method to your `CityCell` class

Comment: I did as above but still same result.

Answer (score 0):

If there ara not so many cells in your tableView,maybe you can use unique CellIdentifier,such as: indexPath.section_indexPath.row